# A Trivial Pursuit #01 (Geography 1/4): History

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, geography, history

<sub>This is part 1 of [A Trivial Pursuit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a60644%20is%3aq%20%22a%20trivial%20pursuit%22&searchOn=3), a 25-part puzzle hunt. Each part is solvable on its own, with the exception of the meta-puzzle at the end.</sub>

---

> HERMITS ERECTED HER – SHE TOLD MERCHANT ALL
> BEST AUTHOR YET, I FELT – PEN-NAME ‘SKIN’
> AN EXPERT’S THIGH – IT THRILLED ME, MATE

[image]

Comment: This puzzle hunt (created by me) will consist of sets of 4 puzzles from each of the 6 'classic' [Trivial Pursuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_Pursuit) categories: Geography, Entertainment, History, Art and Literature, Science and Nature, and Sports and Leisure. The meta-puzzle which follows these will use the answers from the 24 precursor puzzles to wrap up the series. New puzzles will be posted the day after the previous one is solved (life events permitting...). Have fun!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First, we need to resolve the six lines in the quote:

> The six lines are anagrams. Rearranging the letters, we get
>
> HERMITS ERECTED HER --> CHRIST THE REDEEMER
>
> SHE TOLD MERCHANT ALL  --> THE MOTHERLAND CALLS
>
> BEST AUTHOR YET, I FELT  --> THE STATUE OF LIBERTY
>
> PEN-NAME ‘SKIN’  --> MANNEKEN PIS
>
> AN EXPERT’S THIGH  --> THE GREAT SPHINX
>
> IT THRILLED ME, MATE  --> THE LITTLE MERMAID

We can then observe that

> All of the answers are a reference to a statue! Specifically,
>
> **Christ The Redeemer** is a statue of Jesus Christ in Rio de Janeiro, **Brazil**.
>
> **The Motherland Calls** is a statue in Volgograd, **Russia**.
>
> **The Statue of Liberty** is a statue in New York City, **United States**
>
> **Manneken Pis** is a statue in Brussels, **Belgium**
>
> **The Great Sphinx** is a statue in Giza, **Egypt**
>
> **The Little Mermaid** is a statue in Copenhagen, **Denmark**

Noting that

> the lengths of the countries are a perfect match for the grid, we fill them in...
>  [image: Final_answer]
> ...and arrive at the final answer, **ASTUTE**, which is fitting as it is an anagram of **STATUE** (Thanks @Stiv for pointing this out)

Comment: Nice work - in your first step you're just missing a THE for #3, and #4 needs an E instead of the first I (to be completely correct)... Out of personal interest, which one did you solve first? (And can you spot the extra significance of the answer to the puzzle itself?) :)

Comment: @Stiv Ah, my bad. I fixed up the mistakes. Also, spotted the extra significance of the answer. I actually solved the 5th one first.